# How do I prevent an animation in a child view from occurring in the parent view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some code where I have an AnimatedCard.

When I use the view inside another view, the animation has a strange effect on the rest of the view. It goes up and down slowly.

How can I limit the animation to the child view only?

The bug occurs when inside a NavigationView. I need to use NavigationLink for this project so not having NavigationView is not an option.

Here is the code so you can see for yourself:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                AnimatedCard()
                            
                Text("This is some text")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimatedCard: View {
    
    @State private var animate = false

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .blur(radius: 10)
                    .offset(x:animate ? 10 : 130,y:animate ? 20 : 160)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 30 : 0), axis: (x: animate ? 0 : 0.5, y: animate ? 0.2 : 0.7, z: animate ? 0.4 : 0))
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(.pink)
                    .blur(radius: 20)
                    .offset(x: animate ? -120 : 10,y :animate ? -100 : 20)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 80 : 20), axis: (x: animate ? 0.4 : 0, y: animate ? 0 : 0.1, z: animate ? 0 : 0.5))
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.green)
                    .blur(radius: 30)
                    .offset(x: animate ? -60 : 20,y: animate ? 5 : 140)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 20 : 50), axis: (x: animate ? 0 : 0, y: animate ? 0.4 : 0.2, z: animate ? 0.9 : 0.3))
                Capsule()
                    .fill(.mint)
                    .blur(radius: 40)
                    .offset(x: animate ? 60 : 0,y: animate ? -10 : 140)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? -30 : 0), axis: (x: animate ? 0.6 : 0.1, y: animate ? 0.2 : 0.3, z: animate ? 0.1 : 0.4))
                Circle()
                    .fill(.blue)
                    .blur(radius: 50)
                    .offset(x: animate ? 90 : -10,y:animate ? -90 : 40)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 10 : 0), axis: (x: animate ? 0.4 : 0.6, y: animate ? 0.1 : 0, z: animate ? 0.6 : 0.4))
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(.teal)
                    .blur(radius: 60)
                    .offset(x: animate ? -90 : 40,y:animate ? 90 : -20)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? -20 : 10), axis: (x: animate ? 0 : 0.2, y: animate ? 0 : 0 , z: animate ? 0.4 : 0))
                Capsule()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                    .blur(radius: 70)
                    .offset(x: animate ? 10 : 170 ,y:animate ? 0 : -150)
                    .opacity(0.4)
                    .rotation3DEffect(.degrees(animate ? 30 : 0), axis: (x: animate ? 0 : 0.1, y: animate ? 0.5 : 0.1, z: animate ? 0.2 : 0.6))
                
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.25), radius: 25, x: 0, y: 20)
            .onAppear() {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    animate.toggle()
                }
            }
            
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 60,height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height/2)

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is "rest of the view"? `AnimatedCard` is the only view in your code.

Comment: Instead of using `withAnimation`, you could try adding an `.animation` modifier to the view where you do want the animation to happen.

Comment: @Sweeper ContentView is there too

Comment: @BenzyNeez I see, but the animation is reliant of the variable 'animate' being true, how could I do what you suggest for this particular example?

Comment: And `ContentView` is nothing but `AnimatedCard`.

Comment: @Sweeper correct, when I run the code in content view the issue occurs I will put something in there to show you

Comment: Try `.animation(.easeInOut, value: animate)` and get rid of `withAnimation`

Comment: @BenzyNeez, no animation occurs when I tried that

Comment: I realised that the bug only occurs when inside NavigationView. I need to use NavigationLink so not having NavigationView is not an option. I updated the code & question so you can see.

Comment: What happens if you wrap your `withAnimation` call with `Task { @MainActor in ... }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onAppear is called too early. When I added a DispatchQueue to the .onAppear, the issue was fixed.

Replace this:

```
.onAppear {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    animate.toggle()
                }
            }
```

With this:

```
 .onAppear {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                        animate.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
```